# Is $f(x) = x \sqrt{4-x}$ decreasing at $x = 4$?

Tags: calculus, maxima-minima

I am solving a single variable calculus problem and it asks me to determine the decreasing and decreasing intervals of the function $f(x) = x \sqrt{4-x}$. It's pretty clear that from $\left] -\infty , \frac{8}{3} \right[ $ the function is increasing **but**, since the domain of the function goes only until $x = 4$, should I write that the decreasing interval of the function is $\left] \frac{8}{3} , 4 \right[$ or $\left] \frac{8}{3} , 4 \right]$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither.

The derivative of your function $f$ is
$$
f'(x)=\sqrt{4-x}-\frac{x}{2\sqrt{4-x}}=\frac{8-3x}{2\sqrt{4-x}}
$$
for $x<4$ (no differentiability at $4$).

The point $x=8/3$ is a local maximum. Hence the function is decreasing over
$$
[8/3,4]
$$
because, for every $x,y\in [8/3,4]$, if $x<y$ then $f(x)>f(y)$.

The function is increasing over $(-\infty,8/3]$.

Comment: thank you for your input. So I include 8/3 on both intervals? That seems weird - shouldn't I disregard it on both intervals since precisely at 8/3 the function is neither increasing nor decreasing?

Comment: @bru1987 At a single point the function is neither increasing nor decreasing: this notion makes sense over intervals. There is no problem if a point belongs to both the intervals where the function is increasing and decreasing.

Comment: I understand your explanation, but it still seems off. Let me put it another way: would it be actually wrong to use the intervals $]-\infty, 8/3[$ and $]8/3,4]$?

Comment: @bru1987 Yes: the function *is* decreasing over $[8/3,4]$ and you're missing one point.